# Adding options -lc -lstdc++ OR -specs=nosys.specs allows arm-none-eabi-gcc v4.9 for compilation

Tags: linux, gcc, cmake, linker, arm

I added an online modbus library: freemodbus to my project and afterwards I find out that it fails at linkage phase with the following undefined reference:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/armv7e-m/libc_nano.a(lib_a-signalr.o): In function `_kill_r':
/build/newlib-5zwpxE/newlib-2.2.0+git20150830.5a3d536/build_nano/arm-none-eabi/armv7e-m/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/signalr.c:61: undefined reference to `_kill'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/armv7e-m/libc_nano.a(lib_a-signalr.o): In function `_getpid_r':
/build/newlib-5zwpxE/newlib-2.2.0+git20150830.5a3d536/build_nano/arm-none-eabi/armv7e-m/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/signalr.c:97: undefined reference to `_getpid'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/armv7e-m/libc_nano.a(lib_a-fstatr.o): In function `_fstat_r':
/build/newlib-5zwpxE/newlib-2.2.0+git20150830.5a3d536/build_nano/arm-none-eabi/armv7e-m/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/fstatr.c:62: undefined reference to `_fstat'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/armv7e-m/libc_nano.a(lib_a-isattyr.o): In function `_isatty_r':
/build/newlib-5zwpxE/newlib-2.2.0+git20150830.5a3d536/build_nano/arm-none-eabi/armv7e-m/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/isattyr.c:58: undefined reference to `_isatty'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Now after researching online I found out that adding EITHER of the following to the linker options flags solves this issue:

```
1. target_link_libraries(... -lc -lstdc++)
2. target_link_libraries(... -specs=nosys.specs)
```

The first option I think I got related to the fact that the order of those libraries matters so even if they are already included especially libc they would need to be included again or in rite order True?

I just didn't understand the 2nd one: I know it is related to syscalls? Some research brought his to my attention: 
"It seems syscalls are not present. You can use specs nosys.specs or
   rdimon.specs; or use custom syscalls."

Can someone clarify if these are correct assumptions?

Thanks